# WordPress database error with using wpdb->query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a query that is using $wpdb->query but every time I run it, it doesn't seem to work and is providing me with the following error message:

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''4'' at line 1 for query SELECT * FROM wp_mytable OFFSET '4'
```

This is the code that is causing the error:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . MY_TABLE . " OFFSET %s", $offset);
$fetch = $wpdb->get_results($query, 'ARRAY_A');
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've looked at some other questions but nothing seems to be similar to my issue so I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Use %d instead of %s

Comment: I tried that but now it says `near '4' at line 1`. Before the change it said `near ''4'' at line 1`. So it's just removed an apostrophe from either side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offset should be integer not a string. Also offset comes along with limit

Replace

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . MY_TABLE . "  OFFSET %s", $offset);
```

with

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . MY_TABLE . " LIMIT %d OFFSET %d", $limit,$offset);
```

Not tested.

Comment: Hm, I didn't think limit was required when using offset. Well this has fixed it so thank you, was pulling my hair out over this.